# Problem of coordinate conversion between WGS-84 and SK-42 CRS

Tags: python

Today I have a working and tested code in Python that converts coordinates between WGS-84 and SK-42 (in meters) CRS.

To check my own results, I use several reference open resources, including:

- https://epsg.io/transform

Comparison of the results of the reference sources with the results of the my own software code for conversion WGS-84 <–> SK-42 (in meters) gives satisfactory results for the following EPSG codes:

- WGS-84 - EPSG: 4326
- SK-42 (m) - EPSG: 28405, 28406, 28407 (for the territory of Ukraine)

However, my attempts to convert WGS-84 to SK-42 (in degrees) and vice versa with the help of my code (based either **GDAL** or **PYPROJ** libraries) gave a result significantly different from the reference sources for the fillowing EPSG codes:

- WGS-84 - EPSG:4326
- SK-42 (in degrees) - EPSG:4284

I have a suspicion that this happened due to an incorrect use of the EPSG:4284 code, but I lack expertise in this area.

I am attaching the test code and comparison results.

```py
import pandas as pd

dataset_file = './dataset.xlsx'
dataset_sheet = 'WGS84'
dataset = pd.read_excel(dataset_file, sheet_name=dataset_sheet)

sk42_code = 4284 # Pulkovo 42
wgs84_code = 4326 # WGS-84

#### CONVERSION WITH HELP OF PYPROJ

from pyproj import Transformer

transformer = Transformer.from_crs(wgs84_code, sk42_code)
    
res_pyproj = [transformer.transform(row.lon_WGS84, row.lat_WGS84) \
              for _, row in dataset.iterrows()]
res_pyproj = pd.DataFrame(res_pyproj, columns=['lon_SK42', 'lat_SK42'])
```

Calculation results and comparison:

- lon_WGS84, lat_WGS84 — initial WGS-84 data
- lon_SK42, lat_SK42 — the result of conversion using the code above
- lon_SK42_ref, lat_SK42_ref — the result of conversion using reference services such as epsg.io/transform

| lon_WGS84 | lat_WGS84 | lon_SK42 | lat_SK42 | lon_SK42_ref | lat_SK42_ref |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25.8232848 | 51.03326526 | 25.823596 | 51.034175 | 25.825070 | 51.033507 |
| 27.4579144 | 49.33958293 | 27.458209 | 49.340538 | 27.459615 | 49.339819 |
| 29.3043218 | 48.36326457 | 29.304591 | 48.364257 | 29.305968 | 48.363484 |
| 30.8545936 | 47.00415198 | 30.854848 | 47.005186 | 30.856175 | 47.004366 |
| 33.8384791 | 45.31391731 | 33.838698 | 45.315022 | 33.839972 | 45.314109 |
| 36.091232 | 46.81432679 | 36.091392 | 46.815448 | 36.092745 | 46.814460 |
| 38.4155919 | 47.77286782 | 38.415697 | 47.774017 | 38.417105 | 47.772949 |
| 39.9401312 | 49.40683228 | 39.940163 | 49.407962 | 39.941680 | 49.406862 |

I would be grateful for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution!

I added an additional argument `always_xy=True` into the line initiating the transformer:

```
transformer = Transformer.from_crs(wgs84_code, sk42_code, always_xy=True)
```

Now it works. The initial deviation decreased from hundreds meters to less than 1 meter.

Although, it is not clear why it makes the transformer working correctly. According to the [PROJ documentation](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html)

> **always_xy** (bool, default=False) – If true, the transform method will accept as input and return as output coordinates using the traditional GIS order, that is longitude, latitude for geographic CRS and easting, northing for most projected CRS.